# Gitlab publishes build status to only main branch for Jenkins Freestyle Job

Tags: jenkins, build, gitlab, webhooks

I have setup Jenkins-Gitlab Integrations using [recommended settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html#configure-a-jenkins-integration-recommended) for my `dev` branch. I have also added post build status using `Publish build status to GitLab`.

I am only building `dev` branch in my Freestyle job.
Builds are triggering successfully for `dev` branch but their status are showing on the main branch instead.

[image]

**How to move the build status to `dev` branch?**

P.S. I have also checked the webhook logs under Gitlab `Settings` -> `Integrations` -> `Recent Events` -> `View Details`. The Request has `"default_branch": "main",` entry. However there was no option to setup up any branch name in Gitlab Integrations.

I am using default Gitlab (https://gitlab.com) with version `15.3.0-pre 0d272cb0dfd`